# Minimum Euclidean distance between two points and their inverse

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Consider the following two sets $$S=\{s=(s_1,s_2,s_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3: \sum_{i=1}^3 s_i=1, s_i>0\}$$ and $$T=\{t=(t_1,t_2,0)\in \mathbb{R}^3: \sum_{i=1}^2 t_i=1, t_i>0\}.$$ Let $d_1(x,y) = \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$. For every $s \in S,$ there is a unique $t^*\in T$ such that $$d_1(s,t^*)=\min_{t\in T} d_1(s,t).$$ Then, let $d_2(x,y) = \sqrt{(1/x_1-1/y_1)^2+(1/x_2-1/y_2)^2}$ can we conclude that, for every $s \in S,$ there is $\hat{t}\in T$ such that $$d_2(s,\hat{t})=\min_{t\in T} d_2(s,t)?$$

Comment: You could gain much intuition if you draw a figure (S= an equilateral triangle, T a line segment) ...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the reply! Could you elaborate on that a little bit? I can see that $T$ is a line segment on the equilateral triangle $S$, but it's not clear to me how this is related to the inverse.

Comment: My question was silly. I have erased it. But I have another question: is $d_2$ a distance ? (triangle inequality ?)

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, I think I made a mistake in the previous reply, so I deleted it. Yes, I think that $d_2$ is a valid metric that satisfies the triangle inequality. Let $a=(1/x_1,1/x_2,0), b=(1/y_1,1/y_2,0), c=(1/z_1,1/z_2,0),$ where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^3.$ Then, based on the property of Euclidean distance, we have $||a-c||=||a-b+b-c||\leq||a-b||+||b-c||.$